# Multicasting UDP message to local network in unity3d?

Tags: udp, unity-game-engine, multicast

i am wondering if Unity Network engine supporting `multicasting` UDP message to local computers?

how the RPC is implemented in unity? 
are they sending the RPC call from the client to the server and the server sending to all the players? and if so are the server multicasting? of he is sending the RPC call to all the players one by one?